# How to get Updated Device Name in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am using **Build.Device** to get `Android` device name. 
I went to settings and changed the device name. But  **Build.Device**  is not showing me updated Device name what I have changed.

I need to show whatever device name is user changing, How can I Show it.?

I tried with `buletoothAdapter` also but it also don't update the new name programmatically.

Thanks & any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try this `String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;`

Comment: also have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38157223/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar the name of the device, not the device model. It's possible to name the device anything, and OPs question is it not updating when retrieving after updating the name

Comment: after updating i think system need to be boot, try restart the device and check.

Comment: also try [this](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames) library, hope it will help you.

Comment: @HemantParmar overtime I can't ask user to reboot there device to see there new updated name.

Comment: yes, did you try those lib?

Comment: yes, but its not giving me updated name.