# Identify if the android device is one of the samsung edge devices

Tags: android, samsung-edge

I have a requirement in which I have to figure out if my android app is running on one of the samsung edge devices or its a regular android phone. Accordingly my ui would update. All i could gather is that the device name has a substring edge in it. Can someone suggest me a a a better way to do this ?

Comment: I think the only way is to store a list of edge device models in your app, and check current device against this list.

Comment: Yes of course that could be a way. But is there nothing which could inform me of this from the device itself ?

Comment: I don't think that Android itself has any clue about something called *edge*. It is a Samsung-only feature, and I believe there is nothing to identify it in Android OS.

Comment: Yes but devices do come with hardware information

Comment: try to get device name and model and add some if conditions if it works for you. refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38157223/6454463) to get device details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For samsung device's**, take a look at the [Samsung programming guide for Edge](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/edge/edge-guide), in page 10 :

> initialize() initializes Look. You need to initialize the Look package
>   before you can use it. **If the device does not support Look**,
>   SsdkUnsupportedException exception is thrown.
>
> If an SsdkUnsupportedException exception is thrown, check the
>   exception message type using SsdkUnsupportedException.getType(). The
>   following two types of exception messages are defined in the Slook
>   class: 
>   **VENDOR_NOT_SUPPORTED**: The device is not a Samsung device.
>   **DEVICE_NOT_SUPPORTED**: The device does not support the Look package.

So you can do this:

```
Slook slook = new Slook(); 
try { 
    slook.initialize(this); // it is a edge 
} catch(SsdkUnsupportedException e) 
{ 
    // it is not an edge 
}
```

Comment: I believe this will help, will approve the answer once after I implement it